# Scale animation around Safe Area issue in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, view, scale, swiftui-animation, xcode15

I'm attempting to resize a view, but when the view (YellowView) enlarges/shrinks to the safe area, all elements within the view experience a sudden shift (caused by the change in view size). How would you recommend addressing this issue to prevent the abrupt movement?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var scale = false
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ZStack {
                YellowView()
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .offset(x: 100)
                    .scaleEffect(scale ? 0.8 : 1)
                                    
                Button {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 3)) {
                        scale.toggle()
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Scale")
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,alignment: .leading)
                .padding()
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct YellowView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                Text("TopBar")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.gray)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
            
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundStyle(.black)
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            .padding()
            .background(.cyan)
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(.yellow)
    }
    
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should apply `.ignoreSafeArea` after applying the scale effect:

```
YellowView()
    .offset(x: 100)
    .scaleEffect(scale ? 0.8 : 1)
    .ignoresSafeArea()
```

After this you should see that the animation is a bit smoother, but the background fills still jump from "filling the whole safe area" to "not filling any of the safe area". This is because `background` tries to fill the entire safe area by default.

To disable that, pass an empty set to the `ignoresSafeAreaEdges` argument.

```
struct YellowView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                Text("TopBar")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(.gray, ignoresSafeAreaEdges: [])
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
            
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundStyle(.black)
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            .padding()
            .background(.cyan, ignoresSafeAreaEdges: [])
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(.yellow, ignoresSafeAreaEdges: [])
    }
    
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the overload of `background` that takes a `ViewBuilder` closure. This overload doesn't ignore the safe area by default. e.g.

```
.background { Color.yellow }
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'm curious why we should NOT ignore the safe area for the background color. it seems the opposite to me.  Also,
We shouldn't use `.ignoresSafeArea` before applying the scale effect, even if we use it after the scale effect. I comprehend the significance of the order of applying modifiers and their impact on child and parent views. However, it's not entirely clear to me why using `.ignoresSafeArea` both before and after the scale effect prevents it from functioning properly.

Answer (score 2):

So to start with, two small changes are needed:

- `.ignoresSafeArea()` needs to come after scaling:

```swift
YellowView()
    .offset(x: 100)
    .scaleEffect(scale ? 0.8 : 1)
    .ignoresSafeArea()
```

- The way the yellow background is applied  needs to be changed. Instead of using the modifier with round parentheses that takes a `ShapeStyle` as parameter, use curly braces and supply a `ViewBuilder`. This is because the first way ignores the safe area by default, which is why it is "sticking" to the edges. The change means that `.yellow` will need to be qualified as a `Color`:

```swift
.background { Color.yellow }
```

That just leaves the gray background to be corrected. Here too, we could stop it ignoring safe areas with a similar change, but then it no longer fills the area to the top of the view.  So to get it to use the space *as if* ignoring the safe area, it needs to be given more height and then moved up to the top of the view with a negative y-offset. Like this:

```swift
Text("TopBar")
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .background(alignment: .top) {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            Color.gray
                .frame(
                    width: proxy.size.width,
                    height: proxy.frame(in: .named("ZStack")).maxY
                )
                .offset(y: -proxy.frame(in: .named("ZStack")).minY)
        }
    }
```

You will see that a `GeometryReader` is used to find the position of the background in the coordinate space of the `ZStack`. For this to work, it is necessary to name the coordinate space by applying `.coordinateSpace(name: "ZStack")` to the `ZStack`. Having given the gray background more height, a negative y-offset is then used to move it up to align with the top of the `ZStack`.

Here is the full body of the revised `YellowView`:

```swift
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        HStack {
            Text("TopBar")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(alignment: .top) {
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        Color.gray
                            .frame(
                                width: proxy.size.width,
                                height: proxy.frame(in: .named("ZStack")).maxY
                            )
                            .offset(y: -proxy.frame(in: .named("ZStack")).minY)
                    }
                }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
        
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.black)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
        .background(.cyan)
    }
    .padding()
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .coordinateSpace(name: "ZStack")
    .background { Color.yellow }
}
```