# Scale Animation and Safe Area with NavigationStack in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack, xcode15

I'm trying to wrap a content view inside a `NavigationStack`. However, when I use `NavigationStack`, the scale animation shows strange behavior and it does not ignore the safe area either (it works perfectly without `NavigationStack`).  I've already found a solution for the scale animation around the safe area (without `NavigationStack`) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77154511/8630152). `SideMenuControllerView` serves as the parent view responsible for managing all animations related to the content view.

```
struct SideMenuControllerView<Content: View>: View {
    @State private var scale = false
    private var content: Content
    
    
    init(content: Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            content
                .offset(x: 100)
                .scaleEffect(scale ? 0.8 : 1)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            Button {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 3)) {
                    scale.toggle()
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Scale")
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,alignment: .leading)
            .padding()
        }
    }
    
}

struct OrangeView: View {
    @Binding var path: [String]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) { /// <- NOT wroking
            OrangeViewContent()
        }
        //OrangeViewContent() /// <- works fine
    }
}

struct OrangeViewContent: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ZStack {
                Color.orange
                
                HStack {
                    Text("TopBar")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .background { Color.gray }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
                
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "globe")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundStyle(.black)
                    Text("Hello, world!")
                }
                .padding()
                .background{ Color.cyan }
            }
        }
    }
}


#Preview {
    SideMenuControllerView(
        content: OrangeView(path: .constant([]))
    )
}
```

Comment: Do you actually want to scale the whole `NavigationStack`, including titles, search bars and everything? Or do you just want to scale the view inside the `NavigationStack`? I have a suspicion that you are not expected to scale a `NavigationStack`...

Comment: I'd like to scale OrangeView. It's the content of the custom Side Menu. When the user opens the menu whole view (OrangeView) should be scaled down.

Comment: update: I consulted an Apple engineer, and they also recommended the solution proposed by @benzy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modifiers for transformation and ignoring safe area need to be applied directly to `OrangeViewContent`. So now that this content is surrounded by a `NavigationStack`, it means moving the modifiers into `OrangeView` and passing the boolean flag as a parameter to this view.

Like this:

```swift
struct ContentViewTest: View {
    @State private var scale = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            OrangeView(path: .constant([]), scale: scale)

            Button {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 3)) {
                    scale.toggle()
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Scale")
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,alignment: .leading)
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct OrangeView: View {
    @Binding var path: [String]
    let scale: Bool

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            OrangeViewContent()
                .offset(x: 100)
                .scaleEffect(scale ? 0.8 : 1)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}
```

---

*EDIT* Following from your comments, I tried quite hard to find a way to avoid having to move the modifiers inside the `NavigationStack`, but I couldn't get it to work. So the best I can suggest is that you pass the `Bool` as a `Binding` to `SideMenuControllerView` (where it is controlled), so that it can also be passed as a `let` constant to the underlying content view (where it is used, as per my answer above). The parent container would then look something like this:

```swift
@State private var scale = false
var body: some View {
    SideMenuControllerView(
        scale: $scale,
        content: OrangeView(path: .constant([]), scale: scale)
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In my setup, `OrangeView` serves as a parameter to initialize `ContentViewTest`, and `ContentViewTest` is supposed to control animations. Are there any alternative approaches to avoid making changes to `OrangeView`?

Comment: ```ContentViewTest``` is still *controlling* the animation, but it is *performed* at a lower level. The alternative would be to move the ```NavigationStack``` up into ```ContentViewTest```, then you can apply the modifiers directly to ```OrangeView``` instead. Probably doesn't solve your conundrum though.

Comment: I made modifications to the code by substituting ContentViewTest with SideMenuControllerView and additionally incorporated an initializer for it. `SideMenuControllerView` should be responsible for any animation of contentView.

Comment: Answer updated as followup.